# Semantic Search regardless of database type

Tags: python, database, elasticsearch, semantics, opensemanticsearch

I can apply semantic search on a specific table of the database. But my goal is to achieve a module that can use search queries on a related table and database. Any database should be flexibly integrated with the system.

- **Example:**
  Might be possible, my question is ambiguous. In that case here is an example:

**Use Case:**
The search query is "Property rates in Vancouver, BC", in this case, the logic will definitely understand, this query is related to the property database and the location in Vancouver BC. On the other hand, if the search query is "How to turn off the windows computer", the semantic search will understand the relation with the Computer/OS info database. The problem is how can the system choose which database should be used. and what if the "system understood database" is not integrated with the system?

Comment: Are you using NLP?

Comment: yes, @rabbitbr, I'm using NLP. So is it possible to work with dynamic databases?